# error generating storefront id in shopify buy js sdk

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I am super confused with the documentation on Shopify. I wanted to use their Javascript Buy SDK. To follow their simple product fetch example, in the docs, it says that **"Before you can retrieve a product or collection, you need to query for a Storefront ID. After you've obtained either a product ID or collection ID, you can fetch the product or collection using the SDK."**

So using the Shopify Graphiql app and from the example to get a storefront ID, the request looks like this.

```
{
  shop {
    productByHandle(handle: "my-own-product-handle") {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

the expected return id is somewhat like 
`"id": "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzczNDE0OTkzOTk="` in some sort of encoded value. But however the ID I am getting is like a URL. Here is what I got in return.

```
{
  "data": {
    "shop": {
      "productByHandle": {
        "id": "gid://shopify/Product/1349634097238"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "cost": {
      "requestedQueryCost": 2,
      "actualQueryCost": 2,
      "throttleStatus": {
        "maximumAvailable": 1000,
        "currentlyAvailable": 998,
        "restoreRate": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I use this URL to do a request as shown in JS SDK example

```
// Fetch a single product by ID
const productId = 'gid://shopify/Product/13496340972223';

client.product.fetch(productId).then((product) => {
  // Do something with the product
  console.log(product);
});
```

I get the error in the console that **Variable id of type ID! was provided invalid value.**

I am not able to figure out where I am missing the dots.

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Think I have cracked it.... or at least found a work around.  This should be clearer I feel, which makes me think I'm wrong.... anyway, here's what I found out.

When using the Shopify graphiQl app you can ask for the id.  (just as you have shown above).  Take the result and encode it into base64 here..
https://www.base64encode.org/

That will give you the result - 'Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzEzNDk2MzQwOTcyMjIz'.

Stick that in your productId variable and you should get a response.